# DIV pushing down and right but no CSS instructions to do so

Tags: css

I have a div tag titled WADAContainer that is forcing content of a page about 300 px down and to the right of where it should be.  Using chrome the CSS has no instructions to do so?  What am I missing that could be doing this?

Sample URL: http://tinyurl.com/d4yvoo4

Comment: You should include the CSS that is being used for those sections as it is rather relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS contains `160px 0 0 100px !important` for the margin on line 21 of your stylesheet for this WADAContainer. Because you have flagged it as !important, it will not be overwritten `margin:0` later in the stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah, remove the `!important` and it works.

Comment: No drama's, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

comment this line. it will work it out.

```
.WADAContainer {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
/*margin: 160px 0 0 100px !important;*/
width: 950px;
}
```